# Turtle animation is so fast in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, python-3.9

I made windmill but it is moving so fast. I use turtle library to do that and `t2` is only for circle, `t` makes the main job. I use `tracer`/`update` and I tried some numbers inside `tracer` but nothing changed. How can I do that animation at normal speed?

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.tracer(0)         
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t2.speed(2)
t2.forward(50)
t2.setheading(90)
t2.circle(50)
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(2)
def rectangle() :
    t.penup()
    t.forward(170)
    t.left(90)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(5)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(120)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(10)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(120)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(5)
def windmill():
    for i in range(4):
        rectangle()
        t.penup()
        t.goto(0,0)
        t.pendown()
while True:
    t.clear()
    windmill()
    screen.update()
    t.left(10)
```

Comment: Ensuring each "frame" takes a fixed amount of time (say 1/60s, i.e. 60fps) is not easy. But in your simple case you can put `time.sleep(t)` between each move. Either way you need some form of real time measurement in order to be cpu speed independent.

Comment: @freakish so yeah, time works as i wanted. So, i have nothing to do with tracer and update at that point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sleep` method from the built-in `time` module:

```
import turtle
from time import sleep # Imported here

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.tracer(0)         
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t2.forward(50)
t2.setheading(90)
t2.circle(50)
t = turtle.Turtle()
def rectangle() :
    t.penup()
    t.forward(170)
    t.left(90)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(5)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(120)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(10)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(120)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(5)
def windmill():
    for i in range(4):
        rectangle()
        t.penup()
        t.goto(0,0)
        t.pendown()
while True:
    sleep(0.05) # Used here
    t.clear()
    windmill()
    screen.update()
    t.left(10)
```

A **smoother** way is to just reduce the `left` amount for each iteration of the `while` loop:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.tracer(0)         
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t2.forward(50)
t2.setheading(90)
t2.circle(50)
t2.speed(2)
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(2)
def rectangle() :
    t.penup()
    t.forward(170)
    t.left(90)
    t.pendown()
    t.forward(5)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(120)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(10)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(120)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(5)
def windmill():
    for i in range(4):
        rectangle()
        t.penup()
        t.goto(0,0)
        t.pendown()
while True:
    t.clear()
    windmill()
    screen.update()
    t.left(0.2) # Reduced here!
```

Comment: Sleeping is the right idea, but still ties the game loop down to the processing speed. This approach will execute the redrawing/update logic in, say, 0.01 seconds on a fast machine and 0.02 seconds on a slow machine, then sleep for your arbitrary 0.05 seconds (which is already a pretty approximate value, more like a "minimum wait" than an "exact wait"). .07 > .06. With `ontimer`, I think you'll see more consistency because on both slow and fast machines, if they can process the frame logic completely in the shadow of the next-frame timer, then it'll theoretically run the same on both machines.

Comment: In actuality, the `ontimer` approach still suffers from the "minimum guarantee" problem, so it's not perfect, but should be better than `sleep`. I'd be curious to see a truly robust timing solution, but I suspect it's prohibitively hard to implement for most use cases in turtle. Regardless, just reducing the step size or rotation size is not an accurate or portable solution--it's very tightly coupled to how fast the specific computer runs rather than any objective time. Happy to stand corrected if I'm wrong in any of my assertions/assumptions here.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I do that animation at normal speed?

Don't use `while True:` nor `sleep()` in an event-driven world like turtle!  Instead, use a turtle timer event:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def rectangle(t):
    t.forward(50)
    t.left(90)
    t.backward(5)
    t.pendown()

    for _ in range(2):
        t.forward(10)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(120)
        t.right(90)

    t.penup()

def windmill(t):
    for _ in range(4):
        t.penup()
        rectangle(t)
        t.goto(0, 0)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(0)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.setheading(90)

def rotate():
    turtle.clear()
    windmill(turtle)
    screen.update()
    turtle.left(1)

    screen.ontimer(rotate, 40)  # adjust speed via second argument

rotate()

screen.mainloop()
```

You can adjust the second argument to `ontimer()` (in milliseconds) to control how fast the animation runs.