# The problem is that the ball loop keeps looping and you cant control the character because the loop keeps running

Tags: python, python-turtle

I need the moving ball and the key press a/d to work at the same time, but because code runs top down, the ball keeps looping and the key press code never activates so you cant move it at the same time as the ball is moving.

```
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)
t.pensize(5)
t.color("Black")

def Rectangle():
  for i in range(2):
    t.forward(590)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(380)
    t.left(90)

Rectangle()

t.penup()
t.goto(205,100)
t.color("Blue")
t.shape("circle")

A = random.randint(30,60)
B = random.randint(120,150)
C = random.randint(210,240)
D = random.randint(300,330)
Directions = [A, B, C, D]
direct = random.choice(Directions)

def tDirection(direct):
  t.right(direct)
tDirection(direct)
speed = 2
angle = 90

while True:
  color = ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', "purple", "pink", "turquoise"]

  t.forward(speed)
  ty = t.ycor()
  tx = t.xcor()
  #print(ty, tx)

  #breaking out bottom
  if ty < 9:
    Col = random.choice(color)
    while Col == t.color()[0]:
      Col = random.choice(color)
    t.color(Col)
    angleCurr = t.heading()
    if(270>angleCurr>180):
      t.right(angle)
    else:
      t.left(angle)
    t.forward(2)
  #breaking out top
  if ty > 188:
    Col = random.choice(color)
    while Col == t.color()[0]:
      Col = random.choice(color)
    t.color(Col)
    angleCurr = t.heading()
    if(0<angleCurr<90):
      t.right(angle)
    else:
      t.left(angle)
    t.forward(2)
  #breaking out left
  if tx < 11:
    Col = random.choice(color)
    while Col == t.color()[0]:
      Col = random.choice(color)
    t.color(Col)
    angleCurr = t.heading()
    if(180<angleCurr<270):
      t.left(angle)
    else:
      t.right(angle)
    t.forward(2)

  #breaking out right
  if tx > 390:
    Col = random.choice(color)
    while Col == t.color()[0]:
      Col = random.choice(color)
    t.color(Col)
    angleCurr = t.heading()
    if(0<angleCurr<90):
      t.left(angle)
    else:
      t.right(angle)

    t.forward(speed)
##############################################################
#the key press code#
def keyMove(x, y, direction):
    if(not timerUp):      
        #get line of movement from users current position to the end position if they actually move
        #initial position rounded
        x1 = round(x, 3)
        y1 = round(y, 3)
        #final position(potentially) using heading and speed and trig
        x2 = round(x + math.cos(direction / 180 * math.pi) * userSpeed * 3, 3)
        y2 = round(y + math.sin(direction / 180 * math.pi) * userSpeed * 3, 3)
        movementLine = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]

        #check if line of movement is not over any of the wall lines
        canMove = True
        #for each wall line
        for line in lines:
            #if the movement line intersects the current wall line
            if(t(user)):
                canMove = False #can't move
                break
        # move if never set to False
        if(canMove):
            user.forward(userSpeed) 
#########################################################################
#four cardinal movement directions
def kright():
    user.setheading(0)
    keyMove(user.xcor(), user.ycor(), user.heading())

def kleft():
    user.setheading(180)
    keyMove(user.xcor(), user.ycor(), user.heading())
#########################################################################
######events######
startGame()
updateScore(0) #get score to display

#list of keyfunctions 
keyFunctions = [kright, kleft]
keyFunctions += keyFunctions 
# key inputs
keys = ["Right", "Left", "d", "a"]
# loop to get the key inputs to work
for i in range(len(keys)):
    Screen().onkey(keyFunctions[i], keys[i])
```

It just wont run at the same time, do i have to put the movement code inside the loop?

Comment: Please look up how to implement KeyPress events.  That should solve your problem.

Comment: I suggest using [`ontimer` rather than `while True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352) for event-driven turtle programs.