# Why my python kept crashing when it tried to run the turtle.tracer() method in turtle module?

Tags: python, module, turtle-graphics, class-method, python-turtle

I was coding a Snake Game using turtle module but when I add this line into my code the turtle screen and python crashed:

`turtle.tracer(0)`

can somebody help me so I can complete the game? Thanks a lot

my code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, colormode


screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.title("My Snake Game")
screen.tracer(0)
x = 0

segments = []

for turtle in range(3):
    turtle = Turtle("square")
    turtle.color("white")
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0-x, 0)
    x += 20

    segments.append(turtle)


game_is_on = True
screen.update()
while game_is_on:
    for segment in segments:
        segment.forward(20)


screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly by this line?

Comment: I want to turn off the animation of each segment in the line( the Snake's body)  that I created and then use ```turtle.update()``` to update the screen when my snake move.
If you want I can show you my code? Im a beginner and my code only uses the turtle module

Comment: it will be a lot better if you can share your code in the question.

Comment: I added my code in. Thanks for your time!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352) for how to use tracer/update. Avoid `while game_is_on:` in favor of `ontimer`.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to know more about what you mean by 'crashed'.  If you mean everything froze, that's the code you wrote.  Once you introduce `tracer()` you need to provide an `update()` for every change you want the user to see.  But you don't have any `update()` calls in your loop so everything visually remains as it was before the loop.  If you want to see the segments move, you need to do something like:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.title("My Snake Game")
screen.tracer(0)

x = 0

segments = []

for turtle in range(3):
    turtle = Turtle('square')
    turtle.color('white')
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(x)

    x -= 20

    segments.append(turtle)

screen.update()

game_is_on = True

while game_is_on:
    for segment in segments:
        segment.forward(20)

    screen.update()

screen.exitonclick()  # never reached
```

If you mean by 'crashed' that Python quit back to the operating system, then you need to describe the environment under which you're running this code.

Comment: can you make it clearer for me about "describe the environment under which you're running this code."? I don't really get it. Sorry!

Comment: I tested your code and I figured it out, thanks a lot!