# tracer / window update not behaving as expected in making snake game

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

As exactly the same issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70652819/21513363), expecting to see 3 white boxes move across the screen. I tried two variants of the code (including the one posted as the solution above) but got a black screen and this in the terminal.

With error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):File "c:\Users\gil47982\Documents\PythonDocs\snake\main.py", line 63, in segment.forward(20)File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 1637, in forwardself._go(distance)File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 1605, in _goself._goto(ende)File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 3159, in _gotoscreen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\turtle.py", line 753, in pointlistcl = self.cv.coords(item)File "", line 1, in coordsFile "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter_init.py", line 2795, in coordsself.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"

I tried the answer to the original code, as well as my own code and got the error posted above. This is the code I'm expecting to see drawing 3 boxes moving.

My own solution code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

window = Screen()
window.setup(width=600, height=600)
window.bgcolor("black")
window.title("Lucas' Snake Game")
window.tracer(0)

squares = []

xoffset = 0
for _ in range(0,3):
    new_square = Turtle("square")
    new_square.pu()
    new_square.color("light green")
    new_square.setpos(xoffset,0)    
    squares.append(new_square)
    xoffset -= 20

game_is_on = True

while game_is_on:
    for square in squares:
        square.fd(50)
        window.update()

window.exitonclick()
```

Which seems to show just a black screen (presumably, the boxes have moved off?) and the same error code as above. I'm following this through on a Udemy tutorial, and the same code (minor variance in variable names) has the 3 boxes wriggling across the screen.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `fd()` is not a method of `square`.... so this wont work.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352). Avoid `while game_is_on:` in favor of `ontimer`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turtle animation is so fast in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664270/turtle-animation-is-so-fast-in-python)