# Python: Turtle moves slowly when running opencv

Tags: python, opencv, python-turtle, mediapipe

So I'm experimenting with the mediapipe module to control a paddle with hand tracking in a pong game I made with the turtle module. My problem isn't with the hand tracking or moving the paddle but with the ball object for the pong game which moves on its own. I am using opencv to work alongside mediapipe and when I am reading in my videocapture, it slows my ball object, but when I comment it out, the ball moves at the normal speed I set it to.

Here is my while loop to run the screen for the pong game and capture my hand movements. The actual code that involves mediapipe is in a separate file that I am importing as a class. But I think the problem lies with the success, img = cap.read() line. I already have cap initialized to videocapture from my webcam outside of the loop.

```
while True: 
    sc.update()

    # MOVE THE BALL # 
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # AI PLAYER #
    if player2.ycor() < ball.ycor() and abs(player2.ycor() - ball.ycor()) > 20:
        player2.moveUp()
    elif player2.ycor() > ball.ycor() and abs(player2.ycor() - ball.ycor()) > 20:
        player2.moveDown()

    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)
    if len(lmList) != 0:
        fingers = detector.fingersUp()
        if fingers[1] == 1 and fingers[0] == 0: 
            player1.moveUp()
        elif fingers[0] == 1 and fingers[1] == 0: 
            player1.moveDown()
```

Comment: use threads. maybe also use a proper GUI (tkinter or qt or gtk or whatever). -- you know that loops run sequentially, right? so it shouldn't surprise you that `sc.update()` runs once, and then cap.read runs once, and then detector.findHands runs once, etc... before sc.update is called again. -- don't blame the slow camera. blame the AI that detects those hands. it needs a lot of calculation. things take time.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I've tried using the threading module to run the screen and hand detection in separate loops but the turtle module doesn't like multi-threading. Initially, I also thought it was due to my detection function taking too much time but my other objects move perfectly find (my two paddles). It's just the ball object that is slow. As for a proper GUI, I think the turtle module is built from tkinter but I'm not 100% sure. I was just putting my problem out there to see if anyone has any thoughts.

Comment: your ball's position is updated from *that* loop, not from any event handlers/callbacks triggered by the gui. so yes, it'll run as fast or as slow as *that loop* runs. put that ball moving logic elsewhere maybe. it *should* be ok to run just that (`ball.setx...`) in a thread.

Comment: `while True: sc.update()` just slams the CPU as hard as possible, not attempting to establish any sort of framerate or yield to other threads. If opencv is doing a lot of work, then your spin loop will fight against it for CPU time, speeding up and slowing down depending on resource availability. Try [`ontimer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352), which schedules updates a certain number of times a second and gives other tasks a chance to make progress.