# How to play a turtle graphics game using joystick on a raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-turtle, adc, geany

I am trying to use a joystick as a controller for my snake game using a Raspberry Pi. The problem is that my analog signal reader is blocking the code for the game itself. When I load in the game the snake does not move, the analog reader for the movement seems to be not very accurate and glitchy at the same time.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from ADCDevice import *
from turtle import Screen
from snake import Snake
from food import Food
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
import time

Z_Pin = 12      # define Z_Pin
adc = ADCDevice() # Define an ADCDevice class object

def setup():
    global adc
    screen = Screen()
    screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
    screen.bgcolor("black")
    screen.title("My Snake Game")
    screen.tracer(0)

    snake = Snake()
    food = Food()
    scoreboard = Scoreboard()

    if(adc.detectI2C(0x48)): # Detect the pcf8591.
        adc = PCF8591()
    elif(adc.detectI2C(0x4b)): # Detect the ads7830
        adc = ADS7830()
    else:
        print("No correct I2C address found, \n"
        "Please use command 'i2cdetect -y 1' to check the I2C address! \n"
        "Program Exit. \n");
        exit(-1)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)        
    GPIO.setup(Z_Pin,GPIO.IN,GPIO.PUD_UP)   # set Z_Pin to pull-up mode
def loop():
    game_is_on = True
    while game_is_on:   
        snake = Snake()  
        screen = Screen()
        food = Food()
        scoreboard = Scoreboard()
        val_Z = GPIO.input(Z_Pin)       # read digital value of axis Z
        val_Y = adc.analogRead(0)           # read analog value of axis X and Y
        val_X = adc.analogRead(1)
        
        if val_Y > 124 and val_X == 128 or 127:
            print("up")
            snake.up
        elif val_Y < 124 and val_X == 128 or 127:
            print("down")
            snake.down
        elif val_X > 128 or 127 and val_Y == 124 or 125:
            print("right")
            snake.right
        elif val_X < 128 or 127 and val_Y == 124 or 125:
            print("left")
            snake.left
        
        time.sleep(0.01)
        screen.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        snake.move()
        # Detect collision with food.
        if snake.head.distance(food) < 15:
            food.refresh()
            snake.extend()
            scoreboard.increase()

        # Detect collision with wall.
        if snake.head.xcor() > 280 or snake.head.xcor() < -280 or snake.head.ycor() > 280 or snake.head.ycor() < -280:
            game_is_on = False
            scoreboard.game_over()

        # Detect collision with tail.
        for segment in snake.segments:
            if segment == snake.head:
                pass
            elif snake.head.distance(segment) < 10:
                game_is_on = False
                scoreboard.game_over()
    screen.exitonclick()

def destroy():
    adc.close()
    GPIO.cleanup()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ('Program is starting ... ') # Program entrance
    setup()
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # Press ctrl-c to end the program.
        destroy()
```

Comment: For starters, [prefer `ontimer` to `while True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352) to create an event loop.