# Python turtle-module: Onkeypress only available in loop when if-statement fullfilled

Tags: python, loops, python-turtle, onkeypress

I'm attempting to improve a 'Cross the Road'-style game (in scope of Angela Yu's Python-course) with certain player actions that are only executable a limited number of times.

The first I wanted to implement is 'Nitro', an instantaneous speed boost that's consumed on usage. The player starts with 0 nitro and receives one for every 2nd point scored.

At first the following code delivers the desired result, pressing space before receiving the first unit of nitro does nothing. Once nitro reaches 1 though the if-statement never closes again and the player can use nitro an arbitrary number of times. The remove.nitro-function works properly and removes one unit of nitro on each usage, resulting the built-in nitro-ticker to display negative numbers.

I experimented with putting a print-function inside the loop, it behaves like expected (only starts printing once nitro reaches 1 and stopping again when it drops lower).

Why do the onkeypress-functions behave differently?

```
while game_is_on:
screen.update()
time.sleep(.025)
screen.onkeypress(fun=player.move, key='Up')
if scoreboard.nitro >= 1:
    screen.onkeypress(fun=player.nitro, key='space')
    screen.onkeyrelease(fun=scoreboard.remove_nitro, key='space')
car_manager.drive()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `onkeypress()` is not a one-time action, as you seem to expect - *from that point onward*, pressing the specified key will trigger the specified function.  You would normally create all of your key handlers once, before entering the main loop of your game.  The check for whether the player has any nitro or not belongs inside the `nitro()` function.

Comment: The `while game_is_on:` idiom isn't a reliable way to run an update loop. It'll run at variable speeds on different machines. I'd suggest using `ontimer`.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for explaining, I will keep that in mind going forward. Placing the nitro-check within the player.nitro() function unfortunately requires a few adaptions as nitro is currently kept track off in the module scoreboard. I guess I have to turn it into a global variable then. Thanks

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for your input. Shouldn't the time.sleep() function keep the speeds level on all systems?

Comment: @ElvisJr It's certainly better than `while game_is_on:` without a sleep, which just slams the CPU as hard as possible. I admittedly haven't done a precise measure of `ontimer` vs `sleep()`, but I'd like to someday. In the meantime, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352) from the #1 expert on Python turtle here at SO (possibly anywhere). "Don't use `while True:` nor `sleep()` in an event-driven world like turtle! Instead, use a turtle timer event".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your full game context looks like, but as [Jason mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77028963/python-turtle-module-onkeypress-only-available-in-loop-when-if-statement-fullfi#comment135792678_77028963), key handlers should generally be registered once, before your game loop.

Furthermore, only the update loop should process the actions triggered by the currently pressed keys. The handlers are purely for tracking which keys are pressed at a given time. This ensures all the updates happen as a batch and avoids undesirable OS-specific key retrigger behavior.

Finally, the update function is where the game logic (basically, `if` statements) lives. You can compare the current time against your nitro state to grant and revoke nitros and adjust the player's speed accordingly and reposition all of your entities for the tick.

Here's a general proof of concept, a modification of [this realtime turtle boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70979967/6243352), which you can adapt to your specific use case. For the sake of this example, nitros are given freely every 6 seconds, and double the player's speed for 4 seconds. The fundamental ideas are still the same regardless of how scoring and nitro-granting works in your application.

```py
import turtle
from time import perf_counter

def tick():
    global last_nitro_given
    global last_nitro_activated
    global nitros
    t.clear()

    if perf_counter() - last_nitro_given > nitro_given_interval:
        last_nitro_given = perf_counter()
        nitros += 1

    nitro_active = perf_counter() - last_nitro_activated < nitro_duration
    if nitro_active:
        t.write(f"nitros: {nitros} [NITRO ACTIVE!]", font=("Arial", 16))
    else:
        t.write(f"nitros: {nitros}", font=("Arial", 16))

    for action in keys_pressed:
        actions[action]()

    turtle.update()
    win.ontimer(tick, frame_delay_ms)


def use_nitro():
    global nitros
    global last_nitro_activated

    nitro_active = perf_counter() - last_nitro_activated < nitro_duration
    if nitros > 0 and not nitro_active:
        nitros -= 1
        last_nitro_activated = perf_counter()


t = turtle.Turtle()
t.shapesize(2, 2, 2)
turtle.tracer(0)
frame_delay_ms = 1000 // 30
step_speed = 10
nitro_duration = 3
nitro_given_interval = 5
nitros = 0
last_nitro_given = perf_counter()
last_nitro_activated = 0

actions = dict(
    Left=lambda: t.left(step_speed),
    Right=lambda: t.right(step_speed),
    Up=lambda: t.forward(
        step_speed * 2
        if perf_counter() - last_nitro_activated < nitro_duration
        else step_speed
    ),
    space=use_nitro,
)
win = turtle.Screen()
keys_pressed = set()

def bind(key):
    win.onkeypress(lambda: keys_pressed.add(key), key)
    win.onkeyrelease(lambda: keys_pressed.remove(key), key)

for key in actions:
    bind(key)

win.listen()
tick()
win.exitonclick()
```

Note that `global` is poor design, only used here to keep the example reasonably scoped. In a larger app, use some sort of closure like a class or function to avoid globals (it seems you already have a class).

Comment: Thank you very much for this elababorate answer! Really appreciated, particularly the concept of using a 'tick()' is very interesting!

Regarding the usage of global variables, the nitro variable is used in 2 different classes. First in Scoreboard() that provides the HUD for all relevant information, second the Player() wherein it actually gives the player the speed-boost. That means that nitro gets consumed in Player() and that change should then affect Scoreboard(). I think this can only be done using global variables, is there a smarter way to do this / something similar?

Comment: Good question. There are many solutions. One is to keep the nitro in the Player, then have the scoreboard read all relevant information each tick from the Player, and any other entities it needs to display info for. Another approach might be to make Nitro its own class, and pass the instance into the Player class where the player can call method on the Nitro to manipulate it. The scoreboard can also get a reference to the same Nitro and can read information from it. Second approach may be better if Nitro-related logic is complex, first is probably better if it's just an int.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the simple but working idea to just put the following in the main-updateloop: player.nitro = scoreboard.nitro to create basically the same variable in another module! Works great

Comment: That certainly works, but it's a good idea to use setters and getters for that, otherwise directly manipulating properties on classes from outside sort of defeats the purpose of OOP. Usually, you'd set this sort of property in an initializer up front rather than repeatedly in a loop.