# Ball is phasing into paddle in breakout Game in Turtle Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, breakout

So I'm trying to create a breakout game, and the major problem I have is if the ball hits the edges of the paddle, it gets 'stuck' inside the paddle and phases through until the end.

Is there a way to make it so it only runs the check once every X seconds or something?

It also appears to behave oddly when it hits the edges of the bricks as well.

```
from turtle import Screen
import time
from paddle import Paddle
from tile import Tile
from ball import Ball

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1000, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.tracer(0)
screen.title("Breakout Game")

paddle_position = (0, -250)
paddle = Paddle(paddle_position)

x_values = [-400, -200, 0, 200, 400]
y_values = [250, 225, 200, 175, 150, 125, 100]
color = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "teal"]
brick_list = []
for x in x_values:
    for y in y_values:
        color_choice = color[y_values.index(y)]
        tile_position = (x, y)
        tile = Tile(tile_position, color_choice)
        brick_list.append(tile)

ball = Ball()

left_keys = ["a", "A", "Left"]
right_keys = ["d", "D", "Right"]

screen.listen()
for key in left_keys:
    screen.onkeypress(paddle.go_left_start, key)
    screen.onkeyrelease(paddle.go_left_end, key)
for key in right_keys:
    screen.onkeypress(paddle.go_right_start, key)
    screen.onkeyrelease(paddle.go_right_end, key)

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    ball.move()
    if paddle.move_left:
        if paddle.xcor() - 100 > -500:
            x = paddle.xcor()
            x -= 2
            paddle.setx(x)
    if paddle.move_right:
        if paddle.xcor() + 100 < 500:
            x = paddle.xcor()
            x += 2
            paddle.setx(x)
    if ball.xcor() > 480 or ball.xcor() < -480:
        ball.bounce_x()
    for item in brick_list:
        if item.ycor() - 20 <= ball.ycor() <= item.ycor() + 20 and item.xcor() - 100 <= ball.xcor() <= item.xcor() + 100:
            ball.bounce_y()
            item.hideturtle()
            brick_list.remove(item)
## THIS IS MY PADDLE COLLISION
    if paddle.xcor() - 100 <= ball.xcor() <= paddle.xcor() + 100 and ball.ycor() <= paddle.ycor() + 20:
        print(ball.xcor() - paddle.xcor())
        ball.bounce_y()
        
    if ball.ycor() > 280:
        ball.bounce_y()
    screen.update()
```

I'm not sure what I can do, it only happens if it hits the edges of the paddle.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. `bounce_y` is where the collision resolution happens, but it wasn't shown. Are you taking care to reposition the ball outside of the wall when reversing direction? Otherwise, it'll still be in the wall and will just collide again and again. [`while` is a poor idiom for an event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352). This just slams the CPU as hard as possible, and will run at different speeds on different systems. Use `ontimer`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean paddle, not wall, although the same thing applies in the above comment regardless. Also worth looking at: [why not inherit from turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71003069/6243352).