# Turtle not moving forward and also disappears when created

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I moved the tracer place in code and i saw that the turtles are made but after that it disappears and only show on screen when i move it left or right it shows and also mpoves on screen but it wont move forward on its own.

please help me, i have also tried using chatgpt but it didnt gave me a solution.

i have started coding for almost 20 days so i am not good at it.

```
from turtle import Turtle,Screen
import time

scr=Screen()
scr.setup(600,600)
scr.bgcolor("black")
scr.title("Snake Xenzia")
snakes=[]
sp=[(0,0),(-20,0),(-40,0)]
scr.tracer( 0 )
for i in sp:
    snake=Turtle()
    snake.shape( "square" )
    snake.color( "white" )
    snake.pu()
    snake.goto(i)
    snakes.append(snake)


def lft():

    for i in range( (len( snakes ) - 1), 0, -1 ):
        new_x=snakes[ i - 1 ].xcor()
        new_y=snakes[ i - 1 ].ycor()
        snakes[ i ].goto( new_x, new_y )
    snakes[ 0 ].left( 90 )
    snakes[ 0 ].forward( 20 )
    scr.update()


def rit():
    for i in range( (len( snakes ) - 1), 0, -1 ):
        new_x=snakes[ i - 1 ].xcor()
        new_y=snakes[ i - 1 ].ycor()
        snakes[ i ].goto( new_x, new_y )
    snakes[ 0 ].right( 90 )
    snakes[ 0 ].forward( 20 )
    scr.update()

def clr():
    snake.clear()
    snake.home()
scr.listen()
scr.onkey( key="a", fun=lft )
scr.onkey( key="d", fun=rit )
scr.onkey( key="c", fun=clr )
c=True

while True:
    scr.update()
    for i in range( (len( snakes ) - 1), 0, -1 ):
        new_x=snakes[ i - 1 ].xcor()
        new_y=snakes[ i - 1 ].ycor()
        snakes[ i ].goto( new_x, new_y )
    snakes[ 0 ].forward( 20 )



scr.exitonclick()
```

Comment: The first step here is to reduce the code to just what is needed to reproduce the problem. Maybe start a new python file and see if you can write just enough code to duplicate the issue you are asking about.

Comment: You will also need to learn how to debug your code. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is has some great tips to get you started.

Comment: `while True: scr.update()` is not a reliable event loop. That slams the CPU as hard as possible, causing the game to run at different speeds on different machines. Prefer [`ontimer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352). I suggest formatting your code with [Black](https://black.vercel.app/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had figured it out. The problem was that I didn't use any delay each time while the loop was executed. The blocks went out of the screen making it look like nothing is happening and only a black screen is showing.

For that, I introduced `time.sleep(0.1)` in the while loop by importing the `time` module.

```
import time  

while True:
    scr.update()
    time.sleep( 0.1 )
    for i in range( (len( snakes ) - 1), 0, -1 ):
        new_x=snakes[ i - 1 ].xcor()
        new_y=snakes[ i - 1 ].ycor()
        snakes[ i ].goto( new_x, new_y )
    snakes[ 0 ].forward( 20 )
```