# Issue with the movement of paddles in pong game using python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, onkeyup, pong

Turtle onkey is not responding.
For the pong game that i am working on the even though the onkey values are given correctly, the paddles are not responding.

i tried onkeypress as well as suggested by someone on stackoverflow, still doesnt work.
i also checked when passing the function i did not include().

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from paddle import Paddle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(800, 600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("My PONG")
screen.tracer(0)


r_paddle = Paddle()
r_paddle.goto(350, 0)
l_paddle = Paddle()
l_paddle.goto(-350, 0)

game_is_on = True

while game_is_on:
    screen.update()


screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(r_paddle.go_up, "Up")
screen.onkeypress(r_paddle.go_down, "Down")
screen.onkeypress(l_paddle.go_up, "w")
screen.onkeypress(l_paddle.go_down, "s")


screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong.  Right now, your `while` loop will never exit, because `game_is_on` will never go False.  Thus, your `onkeypress` calls will never be seen.

Comment: The language you are using is dependent on indentation. You're not paying attention to that fact.

Comment: Thankyou, I tried moving the while loop below the onkey and listen , it seems to work now.

Answer (score -1):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from paddle import Paddle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(800, 600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("My PONGIE")
screen.tracer(0)


r_paddle = Paddle()
r_paddle.goto(350, 0)
l_paddle = Paddle()
l_paddle.goto(-350, 0)


screen.listen()
screen.onkey(r_paddle.go_up, "Up")
screen.onkey(r_paddle.go_down, "Down")
screen.onkey(l_paddle.go_up, "w")
screen.onkey(l_paddle.go_down, "s")

game_is_on = True

while game_is_on:
    screen.update()


screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Could you explain your code? Although this may solve OP's immediate problem, `while game_is_on: screen.update()` slams the CPU as hard as possible, so this will run at different speeds on different machines and is not recommended. Prefer [`ontimer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).