# How to make a turtle jump in a game?

Tags: python, game-physics, game-development, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I created a code to make my game character jump. I want to input this jump function into my game.

For the code to not be limited to a particular coordinate, I defined `o` as a variable to hold the original `y` coordinate before jumping. In my game, I will be at multiple different `y` coordinates, but if I define it outside I will only be able to jump at a fixed place again. How do I fix this?

```
import turtle

dx = 1
dy = 1.8
mdy = -1.6

img = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\pg\dragon.gif"
turtle.register_shape(img)

scrn = turtle.Screen()
scrn.tracer(0)

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.penup()
player.shape(img)
player.speed(10)
player.goto(100,-142)
scrn.update()

o=player.ycor() #original y coordinate

def jump():
    global dy
    ycor = player.ycor()
    if ycor > o:
        player.sety(ycor + dy)

    if ycor > o+100:
        dy = mdy
    else:
        pass

def jump_handler():
    if player.ycor() <= o+0.1:
        global dy
        dy = 1.8
        player.sety(o+0.1)
        
    else:
        pass

# Set up the event handler for the jump
scrn.listen()
scrn.onkey(jump_handler, "space")

while True:
    scrn.update()
    jump()
```

I tried putting it in the function but that wouldn't work, nor does it work in a while loop. I'm unsure as to how to keep it as the original `y` coordinate without it getting changed during the function.

Comment: Use proper English punctuation in sentences, especially periods and commas.

Comment: My apologies I am not exactly used to using punctuation marks, but will do from now one.

Comment: `else: pass` does nothing; remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your design will work. There's no need to keep track of the original position. Jumping is usually implemented as follows:

- Keep a velocity variable for the y-axis (I prefer `vy` but `dy` "direction y" works too).
- On every frame, subtract a small gravity amount from the player's velocity.
- On every frame, if the player has pressed space, add a large upward velocity. Optionally, ensure the player is touching the ground or a platform before jumping.
- Clamp the velocity to avoid the player falling too quickly.

Generally, in most real-time applications, changes to entity positions should never be done outside of the main update loop. This avoids strange OS-specific retrigger behavior.

Make sure to [use `ontimer` rather than `while True:`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352) to run your loop so that it's stable from one machine to the next. (It'd probably be best to integrate a delta time, but for simplicity, I've omitted it).

Here's a quick proof of concept:

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


def on_space_pressed():
    global space_pressed
    space_pressed = True


def on_space_released():
    global space_pressed
    space_pressed = False


def tick():
    global vy

    if space_pressed and player.ycor() <= ground:
        vy = jump_velocity
        player.sety(player.ycor() + 1)

    vy -= gravity
    vy = max(min_velocity, vy)
    player.sety(player.ycor() + vy)

    if player.ycor() <= ground:
        player.sety(ground)
        vy = 0

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(tick, 1000 // 60)


vx = 0
vy = 0
ground = -100
min_velocity = -25
jump_velocity = 25
gravity = 1

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(0)

space_pressed = False
screen.onkeypress(on_space_pressed, "space")
screen.onkeyrelease(on_space_released, "space")
screen.listen()

player = Turtle()
player.penup()
player.turtlesize(2, 2)
player.shape("square")

tick()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Going a step further and adding horizontal movement might look like:

```py
import time
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


last_time = time.perf_counter()
def tick():
    global vx, vy, last_time

    curr_time = time.perf_counter()
    delta = curr_time - last_time
    last_time = curr_time

    if "space" in keys_pressed and player.ycor() <= ground:
        vy = jump_velocity
        player.sety(player.ycor() + 1)

    vy -= gravity * delta
    vy = max(min_velocity, vy)
    player.sety(player.ycor() + vy)

    if player.ycor() <= ground:
        player.sety(ground)
        vy = 0

    if "Left" in keys_pressed:
        vx -= movement_velocity * delta

    if "Right" in keys_pressed:
        vx += movement_velocity * delta

    player.setx(player.xcor() + vx)
    vx *= friction
    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(tick, 1000 // 60)


vx = 0
vy = 0
ground = -100
friction = 0.8
min_velocity = -25
movement_velocity = 150
jump_velocity = 25
gravity = 50

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(0)
screen.listen()

def bind(key):
    screen.onkeypress(lambda: keys_pressed.add(key), key)
    screen.onkeyrelease(lambda: keys_pressed.remove(key), key)

keys = "space", "Left", "Right"
keys_pressed = set()

for key in keys:
    bind(key)

player = Turtle()
player.penup()
player.turtlesize(2, 2)
player.shape("square")

tick()
screen.exitonclick()
```

There are plenty of improvements to make when the program grows, like avoiding loose global variables (move them into a `Player` class and drop the `global` keyword) and adding functions, left as an exercise to keep the post reasonably scoped.

Comment: Thank you so much i really appreciate this. I just started programming so I'm not all that familiar with classes and global variables but I will try my best to learn. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem and good luck! Actually, real-time turtle games are fairly difficult and there are a lot of pitfalls, so if it seems tough to understand, it's not just you. A library like Pygame might be a bit easier for making a platformer, if that's what you're going for.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that too I started learning a bit of pygame and its easier yes but I still do want to test myself but still thank you!!