# Problem understanding Python's turtle refreshing after using a tracer(0) and an update

Tags: python, optimization, refresh, python-turtle

Lately, I have been trying to create a fake 3D engine with Python. I say fake since it is not really creating a "Z" axis but instead refreshing and recreating what the user is supposed to see every frame. To do that, I am using a relatively basic Raycasting technique (I send multiple rays from my player and every time I send a new one, I slightly tilt their direction. Every time a ray touches a wall, the distance it traveled and its ray number (for example if the 45th ray collides with a wall, its number would be 45) are added to a list amongst other things. All of this is invisible to the user. But then, using this information, multiple vertical lines are drawn with different sizes depending on how far the wall is, or how far the ray has traveled, to reproduce perspective. The thing is, to do all of that, I am using a turtle.tracer(0) and a turtle.update() every time the user presses a key to move so that I can refresh the screen every time the character is supposed to move. The thing is, for some reason, every time the player moves, the screen not only takes a little bit of time to refresh but also turns black (the color of the background) before showing the new image, as if I was using a turtle.clear() outside a turtle.tracer(0), which I am not doing.
Here's my code. I'm not really expecting anyone to read it because it's 250 lines of code but I did specify it.

```
import turtle
import random
import tkinter
xScreenSize = 1225
yScreenSize = 720
turtle.screensize(xScreenSize, yScreenSize)

def _3DTracer(height, RapportDistance, list,AngleTot2D, NbRay):
    """
    Entrees : height -> float , RapoortDistance -> float, list -> list, AngleTot2D -> int, NbRay -> int
    The list contains 4 elements : the current angle, the number of the ray, legth of the ray divided by the max one,
    the difference of brightness this ray has
    """
    #turtle.tracer(0)
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.bgcolor(0,0,0)
    lenList = len(list)
    turtle.pensize(xScreenSize//AngleTot2D)
    WallYCenter = 0
    for f in range(lenList):
        colDif = 250 - list[f][3]
        if colDif > 255:
            colDif = 255
        print(colDif)
        turtle.color(0,0,colDif)
        currentX = list[f][1]/NbRay*xScreenSize - xScreenSize/2
        turtle.pu()
        turtle.goto(currentX, WallYCenter)
        turtle.left(-turtle.heading() - 90) # -> Sets dir to up
        WallHeight = yScreenSize - yScreenSize*list[f][2]
        turtle.forward(WallHeight/2)
        turtle.left(180)
        turtle.pd()
        turtle.forward(WallHeight)
    turtle.pensize(1)
    #turtle.update()
    return 'ok'

def Update3DScreen(NbAngle, NbTot):
    """
    Call: Update3DScreen(NbAngle,NbTot, OriginalAngle)
    Entrees : NbTot -> int
            OriginalAngle, NbAngle -> float
    Return: /
    Everytime this fonction is called, rays a created from the player's position and these rays keep moving strait
    until they collide a wall (using the CheckInsideColliders() fonction)or reach their max range. Then, the direction turns by
    NbAngle et it keeps going "NbTot" times. Everytime a wall is hit by a ray, it is added to the list
    """
    print('NbTot',NbTot)
    AngleEntreChaqueRayon = NbAngle/NbTot
    listOfCollisionsFoundInRay = []
    turtle.pd()
    turtle.tracer(0)
    turtle.goto(currentPos)
    turtle.left(-turtle.heading() + currentPlayerAngle)
    for i in range (NbTot):
        ColorDifference = 0
        hi = 'hi'
        shouldWrite = True
        FreeToMove = True
        count = 0
        tailleMaxLigne = 450
        while FreeToMove:
            turtle.forward(5)
            NotTouchedWall = CheckInsideColliders(FreeToMove, turtle.pos())
            if not NotTouchedWall:
                turtle.left(180)
                newCount =0
                while not NotTouchedWall:
                    turtle.forward(1)
                    NotTouchedWall = CheckInsideColliders(FreeToMove, turtle.pos())
                    newCount += 1
                turtle.left(180)
                listOfCollisionsFoundInRay.append([i * AngleEntreChaqueRayon, i,(count+5-newCount)/tailleMaxLigne, ColorDifference])
                FreeToMove = False
            else:
                newCount = 0
            if count >= tailleMaxLigne:
                FreeToMove = False
                shouldWrite = False
            count += 5 - newCount
            ColorDifference = count*255//tailleMaxLigne - 20

        turtle.goto(currentPos)
        turtle.left(AngleEntreChaqueRayon)
    if len(listOfCollisionsFoundInRay) != 0:
        _3DTracer(0.5, count/tailleMaxLigne, listOfCollisionsFoundInRay, NbAngle, NbTot)
    print(listOfCollisionsFoundInRay)
    turtle.update()
    turtle.left(-turtle.heading())

def CheckInsideColliders(Ok, Pos):
    """
    Call : CheckInsideColliders(bool, Tuple)
    Entrees : Ok -> bool
    Returns : Ok -> bool
    Verifies if the point Pos is situed in a collision zone, inside a wall. If it is, ok takes False,
    otherwise it takes True
    """
    LenColl = len(colliders)
    for hi in range(LenColl):
        if hi != 0 and hi%2 == 1:
            if PreviousPoints[0] > colliders[hi][0]: #le x du nv point est plus petit que celui d avant
                if PreviousPoints[1] > colliders[hi][1]:
                    if Pos[0] > PreviousPoints[0] or Pos[0] < colliders[hi][0] \
                            or Pos[1] > PreviousPoints[1] or Pos[1] < colliders[hi][1]:
                        Ok = True
                    else:
                        return False
                else:
                    # x current > previous but y current < previous
                    if Pos[0] > PreviousPoints[0] or Pos[0] < colliders[hi][0] or Pos[1] < \
                            PreviousPoints[1] or Pos[1] > colliders[hi][1]:
                        Ok = True
                    else:
                        return False
            else: # previous point x < current collider
                if PreviousPoints[1] > colliders[hi][1]:
                    if Pos[0] < PreviousPoints[0] or Pos[0] > colliders[hi][0] \
                        or Pos[1] > PreviousPoints[1] or Pos[1] < colliders[hi][1]:
                        Ok = True
                    else:
                        return False
                else : #previous point x < current collider and previous point y < current collider
                    if Pos[0] < PreviousPoints[0] or Pos[0] > colliders[hi][0] \
                        or Pos[1] < PreviousPoints[1] or Pos[1] > colliders[hi][1]:
                        Ok = True
                    else :
                        return False
        PreviousPoints = colliders[hi]
    return Ok
def up():
  """
  Is called every time the right arrow is pressed. It changes the player's position and then calls Update3DScreen
  to update the 3D perspective
  """
  turtle.tracer(0)
  turtle.goto(currentPos)
  turtle.left(-turtle.heading() + currentPlayerAngle)
  turtle.forward(7)
  globals()['currentPos'] = turtle.pos()
  turtle.clear()
  Update3DScreen(40,80)
  turtle.update()

def down():
  """
  Is called every time the right arrow is pressed. It changes the player's position and then calls Update3DScreen
  to update the 3D perspective
  """
  turtle.tracer(0)
  turtle.goto(currentPos)
  turtle.left(-turtle.heading() + currentPlayerAngle)
  turtle.forward(-7)
  globals()['currentPos'] = turtle.pos()
  turtle.clear()
  Update3DScreen(40,80)
  turtle.update()

def left():
  """
  Is called every time the right arrow is pressed. It changes the camera's direction and then calls Update3DScreen
  to update the 3D perspective
  """
  turtle.tracer(0)
  turtle.goto(currentPos)
  globals()['currentPlayerAngle'] -= 5
  turtle.clear()
  Update3DScreen(40,80)
  turtle.update()

def right():
    """
    Is called every time the right arrow is pressed. It changes the camera's direction and then calls Update3DScreen
    to update the 3D perspective
    """
    #globals()['currentPos'] = (currentPos[0] + 4, currentPos[1]) #globals()[variable] permet de changer une variable
    # globale dans une fonction
    turtle.tracer(0)
    turtle.goto(currentPos)
    globals()['currentPlayerAngle'] += 5
    turtle.clear()
    Update3DScreen(40, 80)
    #turtle.update()

def playerPos():
  """
  When the map is created, it creates a random position for the player to go to that is outside wall collisions. After that,
  it checks for key arrow presses and keeps track of the player's position
  """
  global currentPos
  basePosOk = False
  while not basePosOk:
      currentPos = [random.randint(- xScreenSize//2, xScreenSize//2),
                    random.randint(-yScreenSize//2, yScreenSize//2)]
      basePosOk = CheckInsideColliders(basePosOk, currentPos)
  print("currentPos : ", currentPos)
  turtle.pu()
  turtle.goto(currentPos)
  turtle.pd()
  global currentPlayerAngle
  currentPlayerAngle = 0
  turtle.dot(8)
  global currentPlayerOrientation
  currentPlayerOrientation = 0
  turtle.listen()
  turtle.pu()
  turtle.onkey(up, 'Up')
  turtle.onkey(down, 'Down')
  turtle.onkey(left, 'Left')
  turtle.onkey(right, 'Right')

def echap():
  """
  Fonctionnement : permet de continuer le programme donné dans cette fonction après avoir appuyé sur la touche "Echap"
  Allows the program to keep going when the used finished creating the 2D map by pressing the "escape" arrow. It then makes
  appear the 2D map that was just created and calls the playerPos() fonction.
  """
  print("\n")
  turtle.clear()
  lenColl = len(colliders)
  turtle.tracer(0)
  for i in range(lenColl):
    if i != 0 and i % 2 == 1:
      turtle.pu()
      turtle.goto(previousX, previousY)
      turtle.pd()
      turtle.goto(colliders[i][0], previousY)
      turtle.goto(colliders[i][0], colliders[i][1])
      turtle.goto(previousX, colliders[i][1])
      turtle.goto(previousX, previousY)
      turtle.pu()
    previousX = colliders[i][0]
    previousY = colliders[i][1]
    print(previousX, previousY)
  turtle.update()
  playerPos()

def get_mouse_click_coor(x, y):
  """
    :param x: float
    :param y: float
    Allows the user to create his own map by pressing anywhere on the screen. To keep track of where he pressed, turtle
    places dots on those locations
  """
  colliders.append([x, y])
  turtle.tracer(0)
  turtle.pu()
  turtle.goto(x,y)
  turtle.pd()
  turtle.dot(5)
  turtle.pu()
  turtle.update()
  print(x, y)

help(turtle.pos)
help(turtle.pensize)
turtle.colormode(255)
turtle.listen()  # fait en sorte que turtle vérifie tt le tps que certaines touches aient étées pressées
count = 0
colliders = []
turtle.onscreenclick(get_mouse_click_coor)
turtle.onkey(echap, "Escape")  # si l'utilisateur presse la touche "Echap", la fonction echap se lance
turtle.mainloop()
print(colliders)
```

To see where the problem was, I removed every tracer(0) and update() of the code but, somehow, turtle didn't animate anything. It was just acting as if the turtle.tracer(0) and turtle.update() fonctions were still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone through your code and tried to sort out your `tracer()` issues among other tweaks.  See if it now behaves closer to what you expect:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

xScreenSize = 1225
yScreenSize = 720

def _3DTracer(height, RapportDistance, ray_list, AngleTot2D, NbRay):
    """
    Entrees : height -> float, RapoortDistance -> float, ray_list -> list, AngleTot2D -> int, NbRay -> int
    The ray_list contains 4 elements : the current angle, the number of the ray, length of the ray divided by the max one,
    the difference of brightness this ray has
    """

    # screen.bgcolor('black')

    turtle.clear()
    turtle.penup()

    lenList = len(ray_list)
    turtle.pensize(xScreenSize // AngleTot2D)
    WallYCenter = 0

    for f in range(lenList):
        colDif = 250 - ray_list[f][3]
        if colDif > 255:
            colDif = 255

        turtle.color(0, 0, colDif)
        currentX = ray_list[f][1] / NbRay * xScreenSize - xScreenSize/2
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(currentX, WallYCenter)
        turtle.left(-turtle.heading() - 90)  # -> Sets direction to up
        WallHeight = yScreenSize - yScreenSize * ray_list[f][2]
        turtle.forward(WallHeight/2)
        turtle.left(180)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(WallHeight)

    turtle.pensize(1)
    screen.update()

def Update3DScreen(NbAngle, NbTot):
    """
    Call: Update3DScreen(NbAngle, NbTot)
    Entrees:
        NbAngle -> float
        NbTot -> int
    Return: /
    Every time this function is called, rays are created from the player's position and these rays keep moving straight
    until they collide with a wall (using the CheckInsideColliders() function) or reach their maximum range. Then, the
    direction turns by NbAngle and it keeps going "NbTot" times. Every time a wall is hit by a ray, it is added to a list
    """

    AngleEntreChaqueRayon = NbAngle / NbTot
    listOfCollisionsFoundInRay = []

    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(currentPos)
    turtle.left(currentPlayerAngle - turtle.heading())

    for i in range(NbTot):
        ColorDifference = 0
        # shouldWrite = True
        FreeToMove = True
        my_count = 0
        tailleMaxLigne = 450

        while FreeToMove:
            turtle.forward(5)
            NotTouchedWall = CheckInsideColliders(FreeToMove, turtle.position())
            if not NotTouchedWall:
                turtle.left(180)
                newCount = 0

                while not NotTouchedWall:
                    turtle.forward(1)
                    NotTouchedWall = CheckInsideColliders(FreeToMove, turtle.position())
                    newCount += 1

                turtle.left(180)
                listOfCollisionsFoundInRay.append((i * AngleEntreChaqueRayon, i, (my_count+5 - newCount) / tailleMaxLigne, ColorDifference))
                FreeToMove = False
            else:
                newCount = 0
            if my_count >= tailleMaxLigne:
                FreeToMove = False
                # shouldWrite = False
            my_count += 5 - newCount
            ColorDifference = my_count*255 // tailleMaxLigne-20

        turtle.goto(currentPos)
        turtle.left(AngleEntreChaqueRayon)

    if len(listOfCollisionsFoundInRay) != 0:
        _3DTracer(0.5, count/tailleMaxLigne, listOfCollisionsFoundInRay, NbAngle, NbTot)

    screen.update()
    turtle.left(-turtle.heading())

def CheckInsideColliders(Ok, Pos):
    """
    Call : CheckInsideColliders(bool, Tuple)
    Entrees : Ok -> bool
    Returns : Ok -> bool
    Verifies if the point Pos is situated in a collision zone, inside a wall. If it is, Ok goes False,
    otherwise it goes True
    """

    for i, collider in enumerate(colliders):
        if i != 0 and i%2 == 1:
            if PreviousPoints[0] > collider[0]:  # le x du nv point est plus petit que celui d avant
                if PreviousPoints[1] > collider[1]:
                    if Pos[0] > PreviousPoints[0] or Pos[0] < collider[0] or Pos[1] > PreviousPoints[1] or Pos[1] < collider[1]:
                        Ok = True
                    else:
                        return False
                else:
                    # x current > previous but y current < previous
                    if Pos[0] > PreviousPoints[0] or Pos[0] < collider[0] or Pos[1] < PreviousPoints[1] or Pos[1] > collider[1]:
                        Ok = True
                    else:
                        return False
            else:  # previous point x < current collider
                if PreviousPoints[1] > collider[1]:
                    if Pos[0] < PreviousPoints[0] or Pos[0] > collider[0] or Pos[1] > PreviousPoints[1] or Pos[1] < collider[1]:
                        Ok = True
                    else:
                        return False
                else:  # previous point x < current collider and previous point y < current collider
                    if Pos[0] < PreviousPoints[0] or Pos[0] > collider[0] or Pos[1] < PreviousPoints[1] or Pos[1] > collider[1]:
                        Ok = True
                    else:
                        return False

        PreviousPoints = collider

    return Ok

def up():
    """
    Is called every time the right arrow is pressed. It changes the player's
    position and then calls Update3DScreen to update the 3D perspective
    """

    global currentPos

    turtle.goto(currentPos)
    turtle.left(currentPlayerAngle - turtle.heading())
    turtle.forward(7)
    currentPos = turtle.position()
    turtle.clear()
    Update3DScreen(40, 80)
    screen.update()

def down():
    """
    Is called every time the right arrow is pressed. It changes the player's
    position and then calls Update3DScreen to update the 3D perspective
    """
    global currentPos

    turtle.goto(currentPos)
    turtle.left(currentPlayerAngle - turtle.heading())
    turtle.forward(-7)
    currentPos = turtle.position()

    turtle.clear()
    Update3DScreen(40, 80)
    screen.update()

def left():
    """
    Is called every time the right arrow is pressed. It changes the camera's
    direction and then calls Update3DScreen to update the 3D perspective
    """
    global currentPlayerAngle

    turtle.goto(currentPos)
    currentPlayerAngle -= 5
    turtle.clear()
    Update3DScreen(40, 80)
    screen.update()

def right():
    """
    Is called every time the right arrow is pressed. It changes the camera's
    direction and then calls Update3DScreen to update the 3D perspective
    """

    global currentPlayerAngle

    turtle.goto(currentPos)
    currentPlayerAngle += 5
    turtle.clear()
    Update3DScreen(40, 80)
    screen.update()

def playerPos():
    """
    When the map is created, it creates a random position for the player to
    go to that is outside wall collisions. After that,
    """

    global currentPos, currentPlayerAngle, currentPlayerOrientation

    basePosOk = False

    while not basePosOk:
        currentPos = randint(-xScreenSize//2, xScreenSize//2), randint(-yScreenSize//2, yScreenSize//2)
        basePosOk = CheckInsideColliders(basePosOk, currentPos)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(currentPos)
    turtle.pendown()

    currentPlayerAngle = 0
    turtle.dot(8)
    currentPlayerOrientation = 0
    turtle.penup()

    screen.update()

def echap():
    """
    Fonctionnement : permet de continuer le programme donné dans cette fonction après avoir appuyé sur la touche "Echap"
    Allows the program to keep going when the user finished creating the 2D map by pressing the "escape" arrow. It then
    makes the 2D map appear that was just created and calls the playerPos() function.
    """
    turtle.clear()

    for i, collider in enumerate(colliders):
        if i != 0 and i % 2 == 1:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(previousX, previousY)
            turtle.pendown()

            turtle.goto(collider[0], previousY)
            turtle.goto(collider)
            turtle.goto(previousX, collider[1])
            turtle.goto(previousX, previousY)
            turtle.penup()

        previousX, previousY = collider

    screen.update()
    playerPos()

def get_mouse_click_coor(x, y):
    """
    :param x: float
    :param y: float

    Allows the user to create his own map by pressing anywhere on the screen. To keep
    track of where he pressed, turtle places dots on those locations
    """

    colliders.append((x, y))

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.dot(5)
    screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(xScreenSize, yScreenSize)
screen.tracer(False)
screen.colormode(255)

turtle = Turtle()

count = 0
colliders = []

currentPos = None
currentPlayerAngle = None
currentPlayerOrientation = None

screen.onkey(up, 'Up')
screen.onkey(down, 'Down')
screen.onkey(left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(right, 'Right')
screen.onkey(echap, "Escape")  # si l'utilisateur presse la touche "Echap", la fonction echap se lance
screen.listen()  # fait en sorte que turtle vérifie tt le tps que certaines touches aient étées pressées

screen.onclick(get_mouse_click_coor)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank's that did solve the issue of tracer() working weirdly. For the screen refresh in 3D, it is still strugling a little bit. On this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77798075/23457608, they say that it is a tracer() thing where it is sub-optimal for refreshing the drawing fast to get 30-60 FPS in games for example. Then, they propose a loop using sleep(1) that activates every frame, do you think that would do the trick ?

Comment: @Guigui, never use `sleep()`.  Reread the answer portion of that post.  It proposes a fixed rate timer event to control animation, and having user action events only request changes be made by that timer event, not directly themselves.