# Having problems with Turtle module .pos() function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am making a snake game and there are apples that you need to pick up.

But sometimes when the front part of
the snake that detects if it is touching an apple it doesn't detect an apple sometimes even trough it is on top of an apple. please help.

I have expected apple to teleport to different location when the front part of the snake touches it.
I have tried everything to fix it.

```
from turtle import Turtle

from turtle import Screen

import time

import random

def screen_setup():
    screen.bgcolor("black")
    screen.title("Snake Game")
    screen.listen()

def snake_setup():
    snake.shape("square")
    snake.color("green")
    snake.speed("fastest")
    snake.penup()

def turn_east():
    snake.setheading(0)

def turn_north():
    snake.setheading(90)

def turn_west():
    snake.setheading(180)

def turn_south():
    snake.setheading(270)

def check():
    apple_x = int(apple.xcor())
    apple_y = int(apple.ycor())

    snake_x = int(snake.xcor())
    snake_y = int(snake.ycor())


    if snake_y == apple_y and snake_x == apple_x:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def apple_first_spawn():
    apple_x = int(random.randrange(60, 301, 20))
    apple_y = int(random.randrange(60, 301, 20))
    apple.goto(apple_x, apple_y)

def apple_spawn():
    apple_x = int(random.randrange(60, 301, 20))
    apple_y = int(random.randrange(60, 301, 20))
    apple.goto(apple_x, apple_y)



snake = Turtle()
snake_setup()

screen = Screen()
screen_setup()

text = Turtle()
text.speed("fastest")
text.hideturtle()
text.penup()
text.color("white")
text.sety(screen.window_width() / 2 - 150)
text.write(f"score = 0", move=False, align='center', font=('Arial', 15, 'normal'))

apple = Turtle()
apple.shape("circle")
apple.speed("fastest")
apple.penup()
apple.color("red")
apple_first_spawn()

loop = True
cycle = 0
score = 0
snake_parts = []
got_apple = False
apple_location = apple.pos()
while loop == True:
    cycle += 1
    snake_stamp = snake.stamp()
    snake_parts.append(snake_stamp)
    if check() == True:
        apple_spawn()
        got_apple = True
        score += 1
        text.clear()
        text.write(f"score = {score}", move=False, align='center', font=('Arial', 15, 'normal'))

    if cycle > 3:
        if got_apple == False:
            snake.clearstamp(snake_parts[0])
            snake_parts.pop(0)

    got_apple = False
    snake.forward(20)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen.onkeypress(fun=turn_east, key="d")
    screen.onkeypress(fun=turn_west, key="a")
    screen.onkeypress(fun=turn_south, key="s")
    screen.onkeypress(fun=turn_north, key="w")

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: This game works basically fine for me--the snake can always eat the apple, although a few issues: (1) the apple can spawn on top of the snake body (use a loop and keep trying random positions until you find a valid empty location), (2) `while`/`sleep()` makes for a poor event loop, better to use [`ontimer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352)--this has the added benefit that `exitonclick` will be reachable, (3) key listeners don't need to be re-added in the update loop--add them one time up front.